# Django Rest Framework - Query for exact match on two fields in a mapping table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF and trying to search a mapping table for exact matches so I can update that record.

I have the following tables:

```
site
- id
- location
- address

circuit
- id
- name
- ref

sitecircuits
- site_id
- circuit_id
- active_link
```

my current DRF config as below:

view

```
class MonitoringConnectivitySet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SiteCircuits.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MonitoringSerializerConnectivity
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)   
    filter_class = SiteCircuits
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('site__id','circuit__id')
```

serialiser

```
class MonitoringSerializerConnectivity(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SiteCircuits
        fields = ('site_id','circuit_id','active_link',)
```

url

```
router.register(r'conn_set', views.MonitoringConnectivitySet)
```

this url http://localhost:8100/api/conn_set/?site__id=8&circuit__id=7
returns all the results (as I doesn't search at all)

ive also tried using the below

url:

```
path('conn_set/<int:site_id>/<int:circuit_id>/', views.MonitoringConnectivitySet)
```

serialiser:

```
class MonitoringSerializerConnectivity(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SiteCircuits
        fields = ('site_id','circuit_id','active_link',) 

    def get_queryset(self):
            site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
            circuit_id = self.kwargs['circuit_id']
            return SiteCircuits.objects.filter(site_id=site_id,circuit_id=circuit_id)
```

view:

```
class MonitoringConnectivitySet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SiteCircuits.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MonitoringSerializerConnectivity
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
```

which also fails when using the url (indicating it only takes one value not two
http://localhost:8100/api/conn_set/8/7

does anyone know the right combination here? is there any special needed to be done to filter and update the mapping table?

Thanks

**EDIT**

when overriding the QuerySet I now get the following error:

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  116.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  466.         raise exc

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in list
  40.         queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in filter_queryset
  152.             queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py" in filter_queryset
  90.         filterset = self.get_filterset(request, queryset, view)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py" in get_filterset
  36.         return filterset_class(**kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __init__
  501.                 raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/conn_set/
Exception Value: SiteCircuits() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think simplest solution is to try like this(overriding `get_queryset` method):

```
class MonitoringConnectivitySet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SiteCircuits.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MonitoringSerializerConnectivity
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)   
    # filter_class = SiteCircuits

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(MonitoringConnectivitySet, self).get_queryset()
        site = self.request.query_params.get('site')
        circuit = self.request.query_params.get('circuit')
        if site:
            qs = qs.filter(site_id=site)
        if circuit:
            qs = qs.filter(circuit_id=circuit)
        return qs

 # Usage
 http://localhost:8100/api/conn_set/?site=8&circuit=7
```

Comment: im receiving an error SiteCircuits() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data', I've posted the full traceback in the original question

Comment: I think you should remove **filter_class** attribute from ViewSet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use django-filter here. For that install and follow the [django-filter installation instructions](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/install.html#installation) and use the following code snippet.

```
from django_filters.rest_framework.backends import DjangoFilterBackend


class MonitoringConnectivitySet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SiteCircuits.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MonitoringSerializerConnectivity
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    filter_class = SiteCircuits
    search_fields = ('site__id', 'circuit__id')

    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    filterset_fields = ('site__id', 'circuit__id')
```

Thus, you can use the URL to filter out the results,

```
http://localhost:8100/api/conn_set/?site__id=8&circuit__id=7
```

Comment: It's not necessary to install a third package when the method get_queryset can do it. :) Keep it simple.

Comment: Yeah..but, what if you want to do the same to **N** number of fields? In that case, the code inside the `get_queryset()` method will be ugly

Comment: Apart from that, this package is recommended by the DRF maintainers too... [DRF installation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation)

Comment: **what if** :) 
You can create something more generic inside get_queryset. With a loop. I prefer to avoid third package, because you always need someone to maintain it. But I understand your point of view ;)

Comment: Someone thought about it(generic methods), created some generic things and it got popularity...and thus the third-party packages are born.

Comment: @JPG this option also gives me the error SiteCircuits() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data', any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ive have achieved my desired outcome with the below:

url:

```
path('conn_set/<int:site_id>/<int:circuit_id>/', views.MonitoringConnectivitySet.as_view())
```

serialzier:

```
class MonitoringSerializerConnectivity(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SiteCircuits
        fields = ('site_id','circuit_id','active_link',)
```

view:

```
class MonitoringConnectivitySet(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = MonitoringSerializerConnectivity
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)   

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        site_id = kwargs.get('site_id', '0')
        circuit_id = kwargs.get('circuit_id', '0')
        instance = get_object_or_404(SiteCircuits, site_id=site_id, circuit_id=circuit_id)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        site_id = kwargs.get('site_id', '0')
        circuit_id = kwargs.get('circuit_id', '0')
        instance = get_object_or_404(SiteCircuits, site_id=site_id, circuit_id=circuit_id)
        serializer = MonitoringSerializerConnectivity(instance, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```